# How to write this loops in Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm pretty new to Java 8 and want to rewrite some code.

Any ideas how to write this prettier?

The idea is, that one Person has many Units. One Unit has many requirements. We want to collect all requirements for each unit and multiply them with the amount the person has. In the end we want to output for each distinct unit the name and the amount.

Data example:
Person "a"
- has Unit "u1" 10 times
- has Unit "u2" 15 times

Unit u1
- requires Unit "u2" 3 times
- requires Unit "u3" 1 times

Unit u2
- requires Unit "u3" 3 times

The result should be:
`Your reserved Units:
\#\# 30x u2
\#\# 55x u3`

The code in Java 7 looks like this:

```
    System.out.println("Your reserved Units: ");
    final Map<Unit, Integer> allRequirements = new HashMap<Unit, Integer>();
    // for each unit that is assigned to the person
    for (UnitAmountPerson unitAmountPerson : person.getUnitAmounts()) {

        // go through each unit that is a requirement for this unit
        for (UnitAmountRequirements requirements : unitAmountPerson.getUnit().getRequirements()) {

            // calculate the amount of requirements
            final Unit requiredUnit = requirements.getUnit();
            final int requiredAmount = unitAmountPerson.getAmount() * requirements.getAmount();

            if (!allRequirements.containsKey(requiredUnit)) {
                allRequirements.put(requiredUnit, 0);
            }

            allRequirements.put(requiredUnit, allRequirements.get(requiredUnit) + requiredAmount);
        }
    }

    for (Entry<Unit, Integer> entry : allRequirements.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("## " + entry.getValue() + "x " + entry.getKey());
    }`
```

The entities looks like this:
Person.java

```
public class Person{)
    private Set<UnitAmountPerson> unitAmounts = new HashSet<UnitAmountPerson>();

    public Set<UnitAmountPerson> getUnitAmounts() {
        return unitAmounts;
    }
}
```

Unit.java

```
public class Unit {
    private String name;

    private Set<UnitAmount> unitAmounts = new HashSet<UnitAmount>();

    private Set<UnitAmountRequirements> requirements = new HashSet<UnitAmountRequirements>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<UnitAmountRequirements> getRequirements() {
        return requirements;
    }

    public Set<UnitAmount> getUnitAmounts() {
        return unitAmounts;
    }
}
```

UnitAmount.java

```
public class UnitAmount {
    private Unit unit;
    private int amount;

    public Unit getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(Unit unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

UnitAmountPerson.java

```
public class UnitAmountPerson extends UnitAmount {
    private Person owner;

    public Person getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Person owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

UnitAmountRequirement.java

```
public class UnitAmountRequirements extends UnitAmount {
    private Unit owner;

    public Unit getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Unit owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the following:

```
Map<Unit, Integer> allRequirements = 
    person.getUnitAmounts()
          .stream()
          .flatMap(unitAmountPerson -> 
             unitAmountPerson.getUnit()
                             .getRequirements()
                             .stream()
                             .map(r -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(unitAmountPerson.getAmount(), r))
          )
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             e -> e.getValue().getUnit(),
             e -> e.getKey() * e.getValue().getAmount(),
             Integer::sum
          ));
```

This code  creates a `Stream` over the unit amount. For each one of them, we need to store its amount and the list of its requirements; for that, we flat map the stream to a `Stream<Map.Entry>` where the key is the amount for that unit amount and the value is the flat mapped requirement. We have to resort to using a temporary data holder like `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` to hold those two values since there are no built-in tuple in the API.

Finally, this stream is collected to a `Map` where the key is the requirement's unit and the value is the product of the unit's amount and the requirement's amount. In case of duplicate values, the values are summed.

Comment: Like a charm. Althought I really had to wrap my head around this ;)